# メンテナンスのお知らせ：9月21日（水）9:30〜 JST

Tags: 討議

[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382050/314875) に示されているように、2022年9月21日 水曜日 午前 9時半（日本時間）頃からメンテナンスを予定しています。**サイトは読み取り専用モードになり、質問と回答、広告が表示されます。質問/コメント/回答などを投稿、編集、投票することはできません。** メンテナンスのため読み取り専用であることを示すバナーがサイトに表示されます。

メンテナンスは一時間以内に終了することを予定しています。（詳細はSEページ、[Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) 或いは[ステータス](https://www.stackstatus.net/)のページなどでもご確認いただけます。）ご不便をおかけしますが、何卒ご協力のほどよろしくお願いいたします。